# Maphilight clash with Jquery tabs in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, maphilight

Anybody? Any clue??

I am trying to create two maps with hilightable features on the same page. This works well with all modern browsers (IE11, Chrome, etc) but does NOT work with IE9. You can evidence this with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Sws2T/13/

The script that launches the plugin I paste below for ease of reference. Is there a reason why this gets loaded properly in all browsers but not in IE9? Or is there an issue with my code? The plugin used is 'Maphilight' (https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight)

Thanks in advance,
G

```
$(function () {
    $('.map').maphilight({
        stroke: false,
        fillColor: 'D2D2D2',
        fillOpacity: 1
});
    $('.map2').maphilight({
        stroke: false,
        fillColor: 'D2D2D2',
        fillOpacity: 1
});

    //light up first element
    //this code is repeating below but not sure how to make more condensed
    var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    $('.map, .map2').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    // initialize tabbing
    $(".tabs area:eq(0)").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
    $(".tab-content").each(function () {
        $(this).children(":not(:first)").hide();
    });
    $(".tabs area").each(function (o, i) {
        var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
        d.fillOpacity = 1;
        d.alwaysOn = true;
        $(this).attr("rel", d.fillColor);
        $(this).data('maphilight', d).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
    $(".tabs area").hover(function () {
        var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
        //d.fillOpacity=0.6;
        d.fillColor = "A0A0A0";
        $(this).data('maphilight', d).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    }, function () {
        var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
        //d.fillOpacity=0.6;
        if (typeof d.clicked === "undefined" || d.clicked == false) {
            d.fillColor = $(this).attr("rel");
        } else {
            d.fillColor = "379ee0";

        }
        $(this).data('maphilight', d).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
    //map clicks
    $(".tabs area").click(function () {
        //areas loop:
        $(".tabs area").not(this).each(function (o, i) {
            var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
            d.clicked = false;
            d.fillColor = $(this).attr("rel");
            if (d.alwaysOn === false) {
                //d.alwaysOn = false;
                $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
            }
        });

        var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = true;
        data.fillColor = "379ee0";
        data.clicked = true;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');

        if ($(this).hasClass("current") === false) {
            var thisTarget = $(this).attr("href");
            $(this).parents(".tabs").find('area.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $(this).parents(".tabs").nextAll(".tab-content").children(":visible").fadeOut(1, function () {
                $(thisTarget).fadeIn("normal");
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see it is not the plugin `jQuery Maphilight`, but with the other one - the `jQuery Panzoom`, it appears that Internet Explorer versions below v.9 are not supported:

> Panzoom uses CSS transforms and matrix functions to take advantage of hardware/GPU acceleration in the browser, which means the element can be anything: an image, a video, an iframe, a canvas, text, WHATEVER. And although IE<=8 is not supported, this plugin is future-proof.

See here for details - https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/master/README.md

You say however, that you test with IE 9, how exactly do you perform the tests, is this genuine IE 9 or you run IE 11 in simulated version mode? 
I can confirm, that jsfiddle code works just fine under IE 9 in simulated mode, EXCEPT the zooming with the mouse wheel, it works only with the buttons `Zoom In` / `Zoom Out`.

Comment: Hello bodi0, thank you so much for looking into this. The panzoom feature seems to be working ok -when I remove it completely I still get the issue of the maphilight not loading twice. In fact, if there is a conflict, I think it is with Jquery tabs. If you remove this line in the code `$("#tabs").tabs({});` you will notice that the plugin loads properly...? I use genuine IE9 (my Client's...).

Comment: My advise then is to experiment with older/newer versions of jQuery UI, for example good old 1.8.x or with 2.x

Comment: Hello bodi0, I tried that, with no success. I don't understand what is going on. Do you have any other tips or advice?

Comment: Indeed then there is a library conflict that affects IE 9, my advise is to remove the jQuery UI if you have to support older browser. There are other plugins, which implement tabs and are jQuery based.

Comment: I am not sure I follow bodi0. I cannot remove jQuery UI as I need to build the tabs and the maphilight plugin also requires it. Is a 'noconflict()' solution for this, and, if so, how would it work?

Comment: The `noConflict()` mode is not meant to solve such issues, but to relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable. Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them. BUT - you can try `var $=jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: OK -so this is not the solution then ... :-) I am really struggling with this, any other ideas to fix the problem?